# Ubuntu, how to detach process in a server that opens a window?

Tags: ssh, tmux, gnu-screen

Can you help me with this problem?

I want to detach a process I start in a server. This process is an application with one window/widget (similar to gedit, kate...). I access to the server by means of ssh -X, and run the binary process in a terminal. I have used screen and tmux, but the problem is that once I run the process, the window is oppened remotely from the server to my computer. Then, I would like to let the process openned, so I close the screen/tmux, and once I exit the ssh connection, the terminal waits till I close the process window, thus killing the process in the server.

Is there any way to let the process detached even with the process X windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible over `ssh`. When you have such process, it needs to communicate with the X server (which is running on your client). You can't just take it away from the process.

If you need to run processes with X detached, you need to use X server on that remote machine. For this use case, VNC is probably better solution, since it can create virtual displays that are available even after disconnect.

Comment: So, I need a X client-server like NX client. Only this option¿?

Comment: Nope. Just lookup VNC. Look for the x11vnc package for ubuntu.

Comment: Yes! it worked! VNC with vnc client vinagre. Thank you!!